# idle power consumption of MagSafe 2 45 W A1436 Power Supply

Tags: hardware, power, magsafe, energy

The title says it: plugged into the wall (120vac), but disconnected from the MacBook Air, how much power is consumed by the power supply?

Answer (score 1):

I have measured the consumed energy of an [Apple MagSafe 2 60 W Power Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD565LL/A/apple-60w-magsafe-2-power-adaptermacbook-pro-with-13-inch-retina-display) over a period of three weeks while idle.

The energy consumption drops to **0.00001 kWh per day** after less than 30 minutes since the last usage.

I am confident that the MagSafe 2 45 W Power Adapter will behave the same.

[image: Apple MagSafe 2 60 W Power Adapter]

Note: Other power supplies I have do consume a measurable amount energy with no devices attached. So Apple seems to have done a really great job building these power supplies.